# Copy row in database with the primary key different

Tags: php, mysql

I can copy a row in my database like this:

```
INSERT into `product` (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
    SELECT productCode, title, description, price, productGroup
    FROM `product`  
WHERE productCode = $_GET['id']
```

But I want the `productCode` to be a different **value** to the row I have copied from. I want it to be: `$productCode`

How can I do this?

Comment: does this your code work?

Comment: No because `productCode` is unique

Comment: unique and autoincrement?

Comment: No not autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

You can change the product code value what ever you need to

```
INSERT into `product` (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
SELECT 'your product code value' AS productCode, title, description, price, productGroup
FROM `product`  
WHERE productCode = ".$_GET['id']
```

Comment: is `AS productCode` really needed since it is defined in `...\`product\` (productCode, ...`?

Comment: @Sean No its not needed its just an alias for the value

Answer (score 0):

You can put that into the `insert`:

```
INSERT into `product` (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
    SELECT $productCode, title, description, price, productGroup
    FROM `product`  
WHERE productCode = $_GET['id'];
```

I would recommend that you use a parameter for this and the `id`, if you are calling this from application code.

Comment: I get the error `Unknown column '$productCode' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Maximilian . . . There is no `$productCode` in the `where` clause in this answer.

Comment: this is the actual input `INSERT into product (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup) SELECT 'GH877', title, description, price, productGroup FROM product WHERE productCode = ML292` and the output is `#1054 - Unknown column 'ML292' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
INSERT into `product` ($productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
    SELECT productCode, title, description, price, productGroup
    FROM `product`  
WHERE productCode = $_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into `product` (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
    SELECT $productCode, title, description, price, productGroup
    FROM `product` p
    WHERE p.productCode = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you'd explain what this is doing to the poster :)

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['id'] must in string. wrap id with ' or "

```
'INSERT into product (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup) SELECT'.$productCode.', title, description, price, productGroup FROM product WHERE productCode = "'.$_GET['id'].'"';
```

Comment: Explaining your answer lets others learn rather than reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

do it like :

```
INSERT into `product` (productCode, title, description, price, productGroup)
SELECT "$productCode", title, description, price, productGroup
FROM `product`  
WHERE productCode = ".$_GET['id']
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain your answer and what it's doing :)

Comment: @Emil it's better to think :)

Comment: @Eima No, it really isn't. This is a Q&A site, people come here to learn. They may come to the wrong conclusion, or none at all. It is unquestionably better for you to explain.